# multiple joins to two tables holding fk's

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I'm facing a strange behavior that I must be interpreting wrong, Given that computers always execute exactly what you tell them to, I must be telling it wrong :)

Use Case :
I have a table called `orders_details` that consists of columns of interest, both foreign keys, `order_id` and `product_id`.

I also have a table called `orders` which has a `PK` of `order_id` and a table called `product_details` that has a `PK` of `product_id` column.

The requirement :

Select all orders with their respective order detail and product detail.

What I tried :

```
SELECT ord.shipping_ids, ord.order_id, ord.firstname, ord.lastname, ord.order_id,
ord.payment_id, det.product_id, ord.timestamp, prd.product

FROM  `cscart_orders` AS ord  

LEFT JOIN cscart_order_details AS det ON ord.order_id = det.order_id

LEFT JOIN cscart_product_details AS prd ON prd.product_id = det.product_id
```

Now this results is getting **null** for all the `product_details` columns, so I don't get what I need.

If i replace the 2nd join to an inner join, I get corrupted data (multiple copies of each row without any logical order that I've noticed).

So, What am I missing? Isn't this how joins should work?

Edit :

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f98463/2 -sqlfiddle, Never knew a fiddle exists for sql, sorry for not posting it in the first place.

2nd edit :

my DB tables had data integrity issues :( someone didn't properly set FK's and PK's, 
My original query does indeed work on a sample data, Thanks for pointing me to the right place to double check myself

Comment: Provide a sample of data sets (minimal to reproduce your issue). Good place to do it: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: thanks @AlmaDo - updated sqlfiddle, did not know it exists :)

Comment: Can you give your expected output as per your given sqlfiddle demo?

Comment: the issue was in my db, the queries were all correct. thanks alot for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Your given query working fine on sql fiddle If you give expected output so we can help you.

```
SELECT ord.shipping_ids, ord.order_id, ord.firstname, ord.lastname, ord.order_id,
ord.payment_id, det.product_id, ord.timestamp, prd.product

FROM  `cscart_orders` AS ord  

LEFT JOIN cscart_order_details AS det ON ord.order_id = det.order_id

LEFT JOIN cscart_product_details AS prd ON prd.product_id = det.product_id
```

Comment: Provide your data with sqlfiddle so we can more help you

Comment: Actually you are missing table `orders_details` to join as mentioned in your question and If you provide SQL fiddle then well and good

Comment: Sadly it does not work, I've updated a fiddle with basic columns and data